# Changing text color, dependant on value

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am new to PHP MySQL and jQuery, i am making a service desk form and database, i can input data and display data in a good format. i just need to be able to change color of text dependent on the value in MySQL database; such as status = delayed, in-flight, refueling, take-off, landed, all 5 need to be different colors, such as; Delayed = red, Refuelling = orange, take-off = light green, in-flight = dark green, landed = blue

is there a way to do this?

Comment: use css and create 5 css classes with different colors. then put the classname in your html thus colorizing your data

Comment: I suggest in-flight and landed have other attributes too like bold, underlined as they can clash with others: ie delayed & in-flight, landed & refuelling

Answer (score 0):

If it's a PHP generated page you can write classes in your css file like:

```
.blue {
     color: blue;
}
```

etc...
And then with PHP put the right class based on the value retrieved from MYSQL.
Hope this help.

Comment: better example would be .delayed { colour:red; }

Answer (score 0):

You should fetch the value from database and store it in a variable like so:
$response = DATA FROM DB
then you can use switch statement to check the response and set the color accordingly:

```
switch ($response)
{
 case "delayed":
   // maybe frame the element like so
   <span class="delayed">Delayed</span>
   // or set a class using a variable
   $class = "red";
break;
case "in-flight":
   <span class="in-flight">Delayed</span>
   //or
   $class = "orange";
   break;
   // always good to set a default value 
default:
  code to be executed if n is different from both delayed and in-flight;
}
```

if you used the switch statement to set a classname then you can frame your element just below it like so:

```
 <span class="<?php echo $class; ?>">Delayed</span>
```

then using css

```
.red{
   color: red;
} 

.orange{
   color: orange
 }
```

Comment: just after getting the result from sql and storing it in $response

Comment: can you give example please

Comment: you should start here http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp    
spend a few hours on this website and you should be good to go :)
Here is the switch statement example
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_switch.asp
Are you able to fetch data from sql?